# Array with random Generator using methods

Tags: c#, arrays, random, methods

Hi I'm struggling with this assignment.
When the program starts 4 methods are being executed where the next thing hapens.

- One array gets filled with 100 random numbers between 1 and 1000 000     (method1)
- The first listbox gets filled with aal the numbers from the array        (method2)
- The second listbox gets filled with the 5 smalest numbers from the array (method3)
- The third listbox gets filled with the 5 biggest numbers from the array  (method3)

This has to run when the program starts.

So far my array gets filled and the first listbox gets filled to.
But only in one and not through different methods. I tried to split it up but without success. And my deadline is near.

Sorry for the rookie mistakes btw.

```
public partial class RandomArray : Form
{   
// array met onze 100 waarden
        int[] arrRandomNumbers = new int[100];

        // random variabele
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int iRandomNumber = 0;
        
        public RandomArray()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddNumbers();
        }

        private void AddNumbers()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrRandomNumbers.Length; i++)
            {
                iRandomNumber = randomGenerator.Next(1, 1000000);
                arrRandomNumbers[i] = iRandomNumber;
            }

            foreach (var number in arrRandomNumbers)
            {
                lbxOne.Items.Add(number);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: "So far my array gets filled and the first listbox gets filled to." How is the ListBox getting filled? You're not calling `AddToListBox()` from anywhere that we can see. For the other two, just [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-7.0) the array and then the numbers you're looking for will be at the beginning and the end...

Comment: thats right. this is an attempt to break it up in the codeblocks for the assignment.

Comment: This is a partial class. What does the code in the rest of the class look like?

Comment: @JoshHeaps this is it nothing else.

Comment: No need to have `iRandomNumber` as a field variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you're trying to populate each list in a different function. This is untested but something like this should work:

```
using System.Linq;  //Make sure to add Linq access

public partial class RandomArray : Form
{   
    // array met onze 100 waarden
    int[] arrRandomNumbers = new int[100];

    // random variabele
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int iRandomNumber = 0;
    
    public RandomArray()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating new RandomArray Class.");
        AddNumbers();
        PopulateListOne();
        PopulateListTwo();
        PopulateListThree();
    }

    private void AddNumbers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrRandomNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            iRandomNumber = randomGenerator.Next(1, 1000000);
            arrRandomNumbers[i] = iRandomNumber;
        }
    }

    private void PopulateListOne() {
        Console.WriteLine("All Numbers:");
        foreach (var number in arrRandomNumbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
            //lbxOne.Items.Add(number);
        }
    }

    private void PopulateListTwo() {
        Console.WriteLine("Top 5 Numbers:");
        var top5 = arrRandomNumbers.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(5).ToArray();
        foreach (var number in top5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
            //lbxTwo.Items.Add(number);
        }
    }

    private void PopulateListThree() {
        Console.WriteLine("Bottom 5 Numbers:");
        var bot5 = arrRandomNumbers.OrderBy(x => x).Take(5).ToArray();
        foreach (var number in bot5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
            //lbxThree.Items.Add(number);
        }
    }
}
```

In a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/h3v6n0

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

[image: fig1]

I suggest the following:

1. create a data model to hold the data (the number lists).

   ```
   public class RandomNumberLists
   {
       static readonly Random rng = new Random();

       public RandomNumberLists(int count)
       {
           Numbers = new int[count];
           for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.Length; i++)
           {
               Numbers[i] = rng.Next(1, 1000000);
           }
           MinFive = Numbers.OrderBy((x) => x).Take(5).ToArray();
           MaxFive = Numbers.OrderByDescending((x) => x).Take(5).ToArray();
       }

       public int[] Numbers { get; }
       public int[] MinFive { get; }
       public int[] MaxFive { get; }
   }
   ```

   Use the built-in methods of `.OrderBy()` and `OrderByDescending()` to sort the list of random numbers from bottom to top and top to bottom. Then extract the first *n*-th numbers with the `.Take(n)` method and finally make a copy with the `.ToArray()`.
2. Use the listbox `.DataSource` property to set the items in the listbox for display

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       RandomNumberLists numberLists;

       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           numberLists = new RandomNumberLists(100);
       }

       protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       {
           base.OnLoad(e);

           listBox1.DataSource = numberLists.Numbers;
           listBox2.DataSource = numberLists.MinFive;
           listBox3.DataSource = numberLists.MaxFive;
       }
   }
   ```

   Here I initialize the numbers in the form constructor, and assign the lists to the listboxes in the `.OnLoad()` method which happens before initial display of the form.